# Multiple ManyToManyFields with same through table

Tags: django, django-models, manytomanyfield

I have an `Organization` model and a custom link table model linking it to `User` like this:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class OrganizationUser(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(
        Organization,
        related_name="organization_users",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        "users.User",
        related_name="organization_users",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    link_type = models.CharField(
        choices=LinkTypeChoices.choices,
        max_length=64,
        default=LinkTypeChoices.MEMBER
    )
```

To make it easier to query through to `User` from `Organization`, I want to set up a `ManyToManyField` with `through="app_name.OrganizationUser"`. However, it would be nice to automatically filter this queryset based on the value of `OrganizationUser.link_type`.

Is there any reason why I shouldn't or can't set up two `ManyToManyField`s on `Organization` pointing to `User` through `OrganizationUser` with different `limit_choices_to` values filtering for different values of `OrganizationUser.link_type`?

For example, I would like to be able to write `Organization.owners.all()` and `Organization.members.all()`, running both through the same link table, and get different results.